# Can I put real monuments like white house, statue of liberty in my open world game?

Tags: 3d, copyright, objects, 3d-modeling

I'm currently working on open world game. But I am confused about one thing that, is it ok if I put real monuments and sculptures like white house, statue of liberty etc. in my game? Please help if anyone knows and confident about his/her answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What jurisdiction(s) are you asking about?

Comment: In some cases it might also be relevant if you intend to create a faithful reproduction of the building or more of a comic version of it.

Comment: I added an answer to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/47674/33287) that includes some additional info.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be some restrictions on certain monuments, but not the ones that you asked about at least.

According to [this](https://www.diyphotography.net/10-famous-landmarks-youre-allowed-photograph-commercial-use/), which granted is about photography and not games specifically, some famous monuments have restrictions on using them for commercial purposes, but from what I know of copyright laws, this could also translate to using them in games for commercial purposes. Although, as I said above, the monuments that you mentioned are not included in these restrictions, so you should be safe to use them.

Comment: That article doesn't seem to be a very good reference. It doesn't attempt to be a complete list. It's just a few trivia examples.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! You removed all my worries! Thankyou!